# Water gas is a/the mixture

Tags: articles

> [Water gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_gas) is **a** mixture of hydrogen and carbon monoxide.

Why are we using the indefinite article here and not the definite article? We know that **water gas is the only mixture** of hydrogen and carbon monoxide, and no other mixture can make water gas. Then why is the definite article not being used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odd case where either works, but the meanings are slightly different.

If we think of “water gas” as a general idea of what happens when you mix two gases, then it’s “a” mixture, whereas the contents of a specific container with those gases would be “the” mixture.

If we think of it as a specific mixture as opposed to other mixtures, then it is “the” mixture.